# Why is my CSS not updating in web browser?

Tags: css

When coding my website, I save HTML and CSS docs then refresh my browser to see the changes. However when I refresh the HTML changes are seen but the CSS changes aren't. Instead what I would have to do is close the window and reopen it again to see my CSS changes.

Any ideas why I cant just refresh and see the CSS changes instead of closing the window and reopening?

Comment: Are you running your own server or just executing an HTML file with a browser (i.e. dragging the file to a browser icon).

Comment: That shouldn't be.  What browser are you using.  All I can think of is there is a problem with your browser's cache.  I would recommend clearing your browsers cache and then restarting your browser and see if that solves your problem.  As @ErikReppen asked, are you using a server or just opening files.  If it is the former I would recommend using a free web hosting site 000webhost or create a local environment with something like xampp

Comment: have you tried clearing the browser cache and all cookies. Some servers cache versions of CSS before making them live.

Comment: Also try not-IE any time strange things happen : ) Been at this 6 years and didn't know anything about IE's obsession with the p3p standard leading it to basically !@#$ on anything in an iframe until the beginning of the week.

Comment: @evan.stoddard No I was just assuming perhaps something didn't handle a CSS file correctly on a refresh. Not that I've been doing anything awful with Node.js servers recently.

Comment: Well even then, referencing files can be tricky.

Comment: For the record: ^problem === me, not Node.js which is awesome.

Comment: Thanks for you reply guys. I'm using Chrome. @evan.stoddard

Comment: @ErikReppen i was just talking about referencing files in html outside of a server environment.

Comment: @MichaelSórm In chrome, press `command+shift+backspace` on a mac or if you're on a pc, press `ctrl+shift+backspace`.  Make sure you clear all browsing data including cookies and caches just incase.  See if that works.

Comment: @evan.stoddard Does that mean I have to clear my cache and cookies every time I have would like to see changes?

Comment: @nmagerko Its not a duplicate. The problem with that question was CSS linking error.

Comment: No just once.  This allows you to have an 'empty canvas' to paint with.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try a "hard" refresh of your browser...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache

The idea is to bypass your browser's cache. Different browsers handle this differently, and this wiki article has a nice walk-through for each major browser on how to do this.

Alternatively, you could clear your browser's cache, which is also covered by the wiki article.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this works best! Command + R for Mac on Chrome.

Comment: awesome, saves my day.

Comment: In chrome, you just need to hit:  

Ctrl + Shift + R

Comment: omg ! i need to kiss you ! i on this problem a hour

Comment: Command + Shift + R in chrome on mac is all that works for me.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Sir you are a genius. thank you.

Answer (score 27):

I think it's the cache problem.

**How to locate the problem**

If you are using Chrome or Firefox or Safari, just right click on the page and choose `inspect element`, and choose `network` tab.

Now refresh your page as usual, and you'll see all http request like this:

If the css file status is 304, means browser ask the server the css file, and server says: "no, you don't need to ask me, I gave you the css file before, it has not changed."

If the css file status is 200, but the size is `from cache`, it means the browser do not even ask the server for the file, the browser think he has the newest file.

I think you are in the second condition(200 from cache).

**How to solve this:**

1. you can always clear the browser cache to see the changes. Or you can disable browser cache for debugging purpose.

   But you can't always tell your visitors to clear the cache, so the second method:
2. if you are using PHP or whatever as server language, append a query string to the css file name:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/style.css?ts=<?=time()?>" />`

   99% of the time, this will work.
3. if it's a static html page, you can change the css query string manually(or even the css file name, if you like).

Comment: Everything seems to be fine in the inspector element. File text status say "Success". Maybe its working now?

Comment: Can you post a link of this page? The text status should be a http code.

Comment: being on the inspect element>network tab and hitting cmd+r did the trick

Comment: Man you're second method is amazing :D

Comment: Could you elaborate, if the second case, why does the browser choose to use local cache if it doesn't know if there's an updated version of the file on the server? Or does it actually know?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser, it might be a caching problem.

There may be a setting in your browser that is preventing the Cache from updating.

Have you tried to reset your browser to defaults?

The reason I ask, is Firefox and Chrome handle this way differently.

If you clear the cache+cookies in Firefox, it might not take effect until you close ALL Browser windows.

Chrome will refresh the cache with each individual tab.

I would suggest maybe re-installing your browser because this definitely appears to be a local issue, but not affiliated with the css itself.